# Operating system on the client machine in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to detect the operating system on the client machine in JavaScript?
Please give an example.

Edit: I found a solution here: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm
Is there another way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Comment: Why do you *need* to detect the OS of the client's machine? It's a website, in what way do you need to know about the OS, when it's the browser that's important and handles the work?

Comment: Um, statistics maybe?  Plenty of possible reasons why the OP would want to know the OS besides per-browser website tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

alert('Your OS: '+OSName);
```

Comment: [**DRY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) please? ;)

Comment: This will report MacOS for iOS devices. Sniffing the user agent string needs a great deal of care, attention and regular updating.

Comment: I found the solution mentioned by Ayman El Temsahi http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm